# If I buy an ebook an Amazon, can my son, with another Android device, read my books?

Tags: ebooks, kindle-for-android

When I buy a pocket book both my son and I can happily read it.

I bought some books on the Amazon Kindle store (which I read on my Samsung Galaxy S), and am now wondering: **can my son read these books too ?**

Knowing that the price of an ebook is not that much lower than a pocket version of the same story ( I even found some where the ebook costs more than the pocket equivalent ), I am just realizing that this could not be a good thing to do.

**[--- UPDATE ---]**

Having read the first few answers, I must clarify something: **the Amazon account of my son is NOT the same as my Amazon account**.

I think that for him to access my Kindle store ( as I do as well with my Archos 101 tablet ), I need to give him my login credentials, or am I mistaken ?

*It's not a matter of trust that I should not give him my login credentials. It's just that, I have a lot of items in my wishlist/saved basked that are items I may give to him as a present. And of course , I do not want him to see these items.*

Comment: Create a third, shared account?

Comment: The person using the Kindle app doesn't need to log into it every time. You could log your son into the Kindle app on his phone, and then it should open straight into your shared library after that, so he won't need to know your password. The Kindle store link within the app works with one-click and I can't see any way to get to (non-ebook) purchase history, or saved shopping basket items, though he will be able to buy new ebooks on your account.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Can you create multiple accounts coupled on the same credit card ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kindle, but with Nook you can lend books to other accounts.  Can you do so with Kindle?  Would it be a pain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As per their FAQ:](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200395750#howmany)

> **How many Kindles can I use to access
>   titles in my library?**
>
> Most books you purchase from the
>   Kindle store may be simultaneously
>   accessed for your personal use on up
>   to six Kindles or Kindle-compatible
>   devices (such as Kindle for PC or
>   Kindle for iPhone) registered to your
>   Amazon.com account. If the limit is
>   less than six simultaneous copies for
>   a specific title, you'll see the
>   message "Simultaneous Device usage: Up
>   to X simultaneous devices, per
>   publisher limits" on the Amazon.com
>   detail page.
>
> If you reach the device limit and want
>   to replace one of your current devices
>   with a new one, you must first
>   deregister and delete the content from
>   the device you wish to replace before
>   you can access the content in question
>   from your new device. For device
>   registration instructions, please see
>   the Help page for the device you wish
>   to register/deregister on the Kindle
>   Support pages.
>
> Subscription content such as magazines
>   and blogs can only be downloaded to
>   one Kindle at a time and cannot be
>   accessed from Kindle for PC.

So yes, you can read the ebook on multiple devices, but be aware that there is a limit of 6 (or fewer) devices.

Comment: Also of note, this works with Amazon's Android Appstore as well.

Comment: Can verify this works, I sign into the same Amazon account on my Kindle, my Galaxy S, a Blackberry and my Desktop PC. I can open any of my titles on any of those. One thing to beware of is that if two of you are actually reading the same book at the same time, don't let it sync your position in the book when it asks you, or you could be taken to the **other person's** current page, instead of the last page that you read.

Comment: The page the link to the FAQ points to is now gone.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to register multiple Kindle apps or devices to the one Amazon account.
For example I can read the same book on my Kindle, HTC Desire using the Kinde app and the desktop application on work and home computers.

Answer (score 1):

Some Kindle books have "Lending" enabled on them, so that you can loan them to another Kindle user for up to two weeks. The downside is that this can only be done once per book, and not all publishers allow their books to be leant out.

More info here [Amazon.com Lending Kindle Books](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200549320)

Comment: the idea of lending an ebook seems bizarre to me...